# Match properties using regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string like that represent a set of properties, for example:

> AB=0, TX="123", TEST=LDAP, USR=" ", PROPS="DN=VB, XN=P"

I need to extract this properties in:

1. AB=0
2. TX=123
3. TEST=LDAP
4. USR=
5. PROPS=DN=VB, XN=P

To resolve this problem I tried to use a regex, but without success.

```
public IEnumerable<string> SplitStr(string input)
{
            Regex reg= new Regex("((?<=\")[^\"]*(?=\"(,|$)+)|(?<=,|^)[^,\"]*(?=,|$))", RegexOptions.Compiled);

            foreach (Match match in reg.Matches(input))
            {
                yield return match.Value.Trim(',');
            }
        }
```

I can't find the ideal regex to expected output. With the above regex the output is:

1. AB=0
2. 123
3. TEST=LDAP
4. DN=VB, XN=P

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Does my solution work for you?

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
public static IEnumerable<string> SplitStr(string input)
{
    var matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"(\w+=)(?:""([^""]*)""|(\S+)\b)");
    foreach (Match match in matches)
    {
       yield return string.Concat(match.Groups.Cast<Group>().Skip(1).Select(x => x.Value)).Trim();
    }
}
```

The regex details:

- `(\w+=)` - Group 1: one or more word chars and a `=` char
- `(?:""([^""]*)""|(\S+)\b)` - a non-capturing group matching either of the two alternatives:

  - `"([^"]*)"` - a `"`, then 0 or more chars other than `"` and then a `"`
  - `|` - or
  - `(\S+)\b` - any 1+ chars other than whitespace, as many as possible, up to the word boundary position.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KMRtjK/1).

The `string.Concat(match.Groups.Cast<Group>().Skip(1).Select(x => x.Value)).Trim()` code omits the Group 0 (whole match) value from the groups, takes Group 1, 2 and 3 and concats them into a single string, and trims it afterwards.

[C# test](https://ideone.com/XvsBgT):

```
var s = "AB=0, TX=\"123\", TEST=LDAP, USR=\" \", PROPS=\"DN=VB, XN=P\"";
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", SplitStr(s)));
```

Output:

```
AB=0
TX=123
TEST=LDAP
USR=
PROPS=DN=VB, XN=P
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way could be to use 2 capturing groups where the first group captures the first part including the equals sign and the second group captures the value after the equals sign.

Then you can concatenate the groups and use [Trim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim?view=netframework-4.7.2) to remove the double quotes. If you also want to remove the whitespaces after that, you could use Trim again.

```
([^=\s,]+=)("[^"]+"|[^,\s]+)
```

That will match

- `(` First capturing group

  - `[^=\s,]+=` Match 1+ times not an equals sign, comma or whitespace char, then match `=` (If the property name can contain a comma, you could instead use character class and specify what you would allow to match like for example`[\w,]+`)
- `)` Close group
- `(` Second capturing group

  - `"[^"]+"` Match from opening till closing double quote
  - `|` Or
  - `[^,\s]+` Match 1+ times not a comma or whitespace char
- `)`

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5b%5e%3d%5cs%2c%5d%2b%3d%29%28%22%5b%5e%22%5d%2b%22%7c%5b%5e%2c%5cs%5d%2b%29&i=AB%3d0%2c+TX%3d%22123%22%2c+TEST%3dLDAP%2c+USR%3d%22+%22%2c+PROPS%3d%22DN%3dVB%2c+XN%3dP%22) | [C# demo](https://ideone.com/GHJdzx)

Your code might look like:

```
public IEnumerable<string> SplitStr(string input)
{
    foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, @"([^=\s,]+=)(""[^""]+""|[^,\s]+)"))
    {
        yield return string.Concat(m.Groups[1].Value, m.Groups[2].Value.Trim('"'));
    }
}
```